# FlatMap behavior in scala

Tags: scala, flatmap

I am trying to get the hang of the `flatMap` implementation in Scala. Based on the definition in Scala programming

> Function returning a list of elements as its right argument. It applies the function to each list and returns the concatenation of all function results.

Now to understand this, I have following implementations

```
val listwords = List(List("abc"),List("def"),List("ghi"))

val res2 = listwords flatMap (_+"1")
println(res2) //output- List(L, i, s, t, (, a, b, c, ), 1, L, i, s, t, (, d, e, f, ), 1, L, i, s, t, (, g, h, i, ), 1)

val res3 = listwords flatMap (_.apply(0).toCharArray())
println(res3) //output- List(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)
```

Looking at first output which drives me crazy, why is `List[List[String]]` treated like `List[String]`?

After all with answer for above question, someone please help me to perform an operation which needs to pick the first character of the first string of each inner and result in a `List[Char]`. So given the `listwords`, I want the output to be `List('a', 'd', 'g')`.

Answer (score 1):

`List("abc") + "1"` is equivalent to `List("abc").toString + "1"` so it returns the string "List(a, b, c)1". The type of `List.flatMap` is

```
flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ GenTraversableOnce[B]): List[B]
```

and your function has type `(List[String] => String)`. `String` extends `GenTraversableOnce[Char]` so your result list has type `List[Char]`.

Answer (score 1):

The code `listwords flatMap (_+"1")` can be rewritten as `listwords flatMap (list => list.toString + "1")`. So you basically transformed all lists to strings using toString method.

To obtain first characters you can use the following expression:

```
listwords.flatMap(_.headOption).flatMap(_.headOption)
```

Comment: You don't have to call `headOption` twice:
`listwords.flatMap(_.flatMap(_.headOption))`

Comment: You do need `headOption` twice because you only want the first character of the *first* string.

Answer (score 0):

`_+"1"` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

It's interpreted as `list: List[String] => list.+("1")`

Since `List[String]` doesn't contain such a method, the compiler looks for an implicit conversion in scope. It finds `any2stringadd`. (See http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions for more on implicit conversions)

```scala
implicit final class any2stringadd[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
  def +(other: String): String = String.valueOf(self) + other
}
```

`list: List[String] => list.+("1")`

now turns into

`list: List[String] => new any2stringadd(list).+("1")`

which returns `String.valueOf(list) + "1"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand the difference between the `map` and the `flatMap` methods. Both of them iterate over some container and apply a function literal to every element. The difference is that the `flatMap` is making one more additional operation: it flattens the structure of the container. There is also a method that allows you just to do the flattening and its called `flatten` (so the `flatMap` is the equivalent of the `map` operation followed by the `flatten` operation). The second thing you have to remember is that you're modifying (mapping over) nested lists, so you need to nest your `map`/`flatMap` calls as well. Those examples should clarify all of those things to you:

```scala
scala> val wordLists = List(List("abc"),List("de"),List("f"), List())
wordLists: List[List[String]] = List(List(abc), List(de), List(f), List())

scala> val words = wordsLists.flatten
words: List[String] = List(abc, de, f)

scala> val replacedWordLists = wordsLists.map(_ => List("xyz"))
replacedWordLists: List[List[String]] = List(List(xyz), List(xyz), List(xyz), List(xyz))

scala> val replacedWords = wordsLists.map(_ => List("xyz")).flatten // Equivalent: wordsLists.flatMap(_ => List("xyz"))
replacedWords: List[String] = List(xyz, xyz, xyz, xyz)

scala> val upperCaseWordLists = wordsLists.map(_.map(_.toUpperCase))
upperCaseWordLists: List[List[String]] = List(List(ABC), List(DE), List(F), List())

scala> val upperCaseWords = wordsLists.map(_.map(_.toUpperCase)).flatten // Equivalent: wordsLists.flatMap(_.map(_.toUpperCase))
upperCaseWords: List[String] = List(ABC, DE, F)

scala> val optionalFirstLetterLists = wordLists.map(_.map(_.headOption))
optionalFirstLetterLists: List[List[Option[Char]]] = List(List(Some(a)), List(Some(d)), List(Some(f)), List())

scala> val optionalFirstLetters = wordLists.map(_.map(_.headOption)).flatten // Equivalent: wordLists.flatMap(_.map(_.headOption))
optionalFirstLetters: List[Option[Char]] = List(Some(a), Some(d), Some(f))

scala> val firstLetterLists = wordLists.map(_.map(_.headOption).flatten) // Equivalent: wordLists.map(_.flatMap(_.headOption))
firstLetterLists: List[List[Char]] = List(List(a), List(d), List(f), List())

scala> val firstLetters = wordLists.map(_.flatMap(_.headOption)).flatten // Equivalent: wordLists.flatMap(_.flatMap(_.headOption))
firstLetters: List[Char] = List(a, d, f)
```